# The correct way to log, and where to log, in PHP

Tags: php, logging

I have firePHP installed for logging to the console, but that's mostly for debugging. I want to be able to log to a file if something bad occurs on PHP scripts when a user is calling it. To do this, I was just planning to create a log.txt file and create functions that write to the file whenever an exception reaches the catch block, and maybe even send me an email if things are really bad. Is this the conventional way of doing things? Ideally where should the log file be placed in the directory structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use stream files for logging. You will inevitably end up with contention or locking issues. Every modern operating system provides a facility for recording log entries which is accessible from PHP. Most webservers will record anything written to stderr by PHP in their error log.

Comment: Ideally where should the log file be placed in the directory structure?

Comment: That depends on which logging facility you use, what operating system it runs on, what your security model is, what your support model is.....